# How do I use my exctracted properties from @PropertySource

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I'm trying to use **@PropertySource** in order to load properties from a *.properties* file and use them in my Spring-batch.

I have a Config.java file which is suppose to load those properties, an application.properties files with data in it, and I'm trying to access those data by an instance of Config.java in another file. But it looks like the Config object is empty.

This is the **Config.java** file :

```
package demo;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;

@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:config/application.properties")
public class Config {

    @Autowired Environment env;

    //Attempt number 1
    @Value("${source.name}")
    public String name;

    //Attempt number 2
    public String getSource(){
        return env.getProperty("source.name"); 
    }

}
```

The **application.properties** file :

```
source.name="OPTIQ"
```

And another file where I'm trying to reach this particular line (I've removed a lot of process but only these lines are important):

```
public class Process{

   @Autowired Config configuration;
   String source;

   public setSource(){
       this.source = configuration.source;
       // this.source = configuration.getSource();
   }

}
```

The result would be "OPTIQ" but the configuration object seems to be empty or not initialized so I guess I'm missing one step here or I don't fully understant how the **@PropertySource** works.

I don't have file access error, he seems to find the file.

The first question is, which attempt is correct : 
 - number 1 with @Value ?
 - number 2 with public getSource() ?
Second question : 
What do I need to change in order to make this right ?

Comment: If Config is empty maybe you are missing @Autowired annotation on you Config field in Process class?

Comment: @Spasoje even with that, the object is still empty...

Comment: Interested how do you initialize `configuration` if not `@Autowired`? And how is your Process class initialized? Autowire will not work if you do `new Process(..)`

Comment: You're right @pirho , I was doing `new Process()` somewhere else. I'm not really confortable with annotations and spring. What do you think would be the best way to achieve what I'm trying to do here ?

Answer (score 0):

Autowire the `org.springframework.core.env.Environment` in your class. Then you will be able to access the properties using `environment.getProperty(propertyName)`;

```
@Component
public class Process{
   @Autowired
   private Environment environment;
   public void yourMethod(){
  // access it as below wherever required.
   environment.getProperty(propertyName);
 }
}
```

Also add `@PropertySource` on Config class.

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:some.properties")
public class Config {

}
```

Comment: `environment` seems to be empty when I'm doing this. 
But I don't get it, what is the use of the `Config` class if we're using the Autowire `Environment` in my `Process` class ? Is it just to inform the source of the properties ?

Comment: Its where you may define some your custom bean definitions. Normally component-scanning does creates beans for you. But if you want any bean with some settings set explicitly by you, then you specify those in @config annotated class. Ref:https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Configuration.html

Comment: I see, do you think my `Environment` problem is due to the initilization of my `Process`class ? Or should the `environment` be accesssible from everywhere ?

Comment: Your Process class should be created via spring only. If you create any object by explicitly  calling constructor, then it wont be having all the dependencies  like Environment and any other feature of spring injected.  Your Process class should be annotated with @Component annotation, so that spring will create a object for you.

Comment: This should inject Environment in your Process Bean and it wont be null